# Função clonar valor pilha

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, stack, codeblocks

Olá, tenho uma atividade que me pede algumas funções, dentre elas uma função clonaValorPilha(struct no **Pilha)  (sendo obrigatório essa forma), porém sempre que eu tento compilar o que está escrito não dá certo, e quando é possível compilar o código crasha quando chega nessa parte, podem me mostrar o que fiz de errado?

```
                #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <locale.h>
            #include <stdbool.h>


            typedef struct no {
                int qnt;
                int dados[];
            } no;

            no* cria() {
                int qnt=0;
                int dados=0;
                no *L = malloc(sizeof(no));
                if (L != NULL) {
                    L->qnt = 0;
                }
                return L;
            }

            struct clone {
                        int qnt;
                        int dados[];
            }clone;

            struct Pilha {

                int qnt;
                float *dados;

            };

            struct PilhaClone {

                int qnt;
                float *dados;

            }PilhaClone;

            void criarpilha( struct Pilha *p){

               p->qnt = 0;
               p->dados = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

            }


            void insere(no *L, int valor) {

                L->dados[L->qnt] = valor;
                L->qnt++;

            }
            void exibe(no *L) {
                for (int i = 0; i < L->qnt; i++)
                    printf("%3d\n", L->dados[i]);
            }

            void exibeClone(no *L) {
                for (clone.qnt= 0; clone.qnt < L->qnt; clone.qnt++)
                    printf("%i\n", clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
            }

            no* inverteLista(struct no *L) {
                no *outra = cria();
                while (L->qnt > 0) {
                    outra->dados[outra->qnt] = L->dados[L->qnt - 1];
                    L->qnt--;
                    outra->qnt++;
                }
                return outra;
            }

            void clonaValorLista(struct no *L) {
                    for (clone.qnt=0; clone.qnt<L->qnt; clone.qnt++){
                    clone.dados[clone.qnt] = L->dados[clone.qnt];
                    printf("%i\n",clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
                    }
            }

            void push ( struct Pilha *p, float v){

                p->qnt++;
                p->dados[p->qnt] = v;

            }

            void imprimePilhaPrincipal (struct Pilha *p){

                        int aux = p->qnt;
                            printf("teste %i\n",p->qnt);

            }

            float retornaqnt ( struct Pilha *p ){

               return p->dados [p->qnt];

            }

            void clonaValorPilha(struct no **Pilha){
                (**Pilha).qnt=0;
                for (PilhaClone.qnt=0; PilhaClone.qnt<Pilha->qnt; PilhaClone.qnt++){
                    PilhaClone.dados[PilhaClone.qnt] = Pilha->qnt[PilhaClone.qnt];
                    printf("%i\n",PilhaClone.dados[PilhaClone.qnt]);
            }






            int desempilhar ( struct Pilha *p ){

               int aux = p->dados [p->qnt];
               p->qnt--;
               return aux;

            }




            int main() {
                setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
                int valor,op,valorPilha;
                bool listaClonada = false;
                no *L = cria();
                no *clone = cria();
                struct Pilha minhapilha;
                criarpilha (&minhapilha);

                while( 1 ){
                    printf("\n1- Informar Valores Da Lista Principal \n");
                    printf("2- Função clonaValorLista (Clona lista Principal)\n");
                    printf("3- Exibe lista clonada\n");
                    printf("4- Exibe lista principal \n");
                    printf("5- Função inverteLista (Inverte a lista Original)\n");
                    printf("6- Inserir Valor No Topo Da Pilha Principal\n");
                    printf("7- Imprimir Pilha Principal\n");
                    printf("8- Função clonaValorPilha\n");
                    printf("10- sair\n");

                    printf("\nSelecione A Opção: ");
                    scanf("%i", &op);
                    fflush(stdin);


                    switch (op){

                        case 1:
                            printf("Informe o valor:");
                            scanf("%i", &valor);
                            insere(L, valor);
                            break;

                            case 2:
                                printf("Lista Clonada\n");
                                clonaValorLista(L);
                                listaClonada = true;

                            break;

                            case 3:
                            if (listaClonada == false){
                                printf("\nLista ainda não clonada\n");
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("\nValores Clonados\n");
                                exibeClone(L);
                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            printf("\nValores\n");
                            exibe(L);
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            printf("\nValores Originais:\n");
                            exibe(L);
                            L = inverteLista(L);
                            printf("\nValores Invertidos:\n");
                            exibe(L);
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            printf("\nInsira o valor para adicionar ao qnt da pilha princpal: ");
                            scanf("%i",&valorPilha);
                            push (&minhapilha, valorPilha);
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
                                printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
                            }
                            else{
                                printf("\nPilha Principal\n");
                                int aux=minhapilha.qnt;
                                for (minhapilha.qnt; minhapilha.qnt>0; minhapilha.qnt--){
                                    valorPilha = retornaqnt(&minhapilha);
                                    printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
                                }
                                minhapilha.qnt=aux;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            clonaValorPilha(&minhapilha);
                            break;


                        case 10:
                            exit(0);
                    }
                }





            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Creio que você deva criar algumas funções, como pushclone e criaclone e fazer a rotina de clonagem gerando as informações de forma similar ao que fez para popular os dados da pilha principal.

```
if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
   printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nPilha Clonada\n");
    int aux=minhapilha.qnt;
    int x= minhapilha.qnt;
    for (x; x>0; x--){
        valorPilha = minhapilha.dados[x];
        pushclone(&minhapilhaclone,valorPilha);
        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
    }
    minhapilhaclone.qnt=aux;
}
break;
```

Claro que você deve fazer a função conforme solicitado, mas, o projeto com a opção de clonagem esta funcional e compilando normalmente com o código a seguir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct no {
    int qnt;
    int dados[];
} no;

no* cria() {
    int qnt=0;
    int dados=0;
    no *L = (no *) malloc(sizeof(no));
    if (L != NULL) {
        L->qnt = 0;
    }
    return L;
}

struct clone {
            int qnt;
            int dados[];
}clone;

struct Pilha {

    int qnt;
    float *dados;

};

struct PilhaClone {

    int qnt;
    float *dados;

}PilhaClone;

void criarpilha( struct Pilha *p){

    p->qnt = 0;
    p->dados = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

}



void criarpilhaclone( struct PilhaClone *p){

    p->qnt = 0;
    p->dados = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

}

void insere(no *L, int valor) {

    L->dados[L->qnt] = valor;
    L->qnt++;

}

void exibe(no *L) {
    for (int i = 0; i < L->qnt; i++)
        printf("%3d\n", L->dados[i]);
}

void exibeClone(no *L) {
    for (clone.qnt= 0; clone.qnt < L->qnt; clone.qnt++)
        printf("%i\n", clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
}

no* inverteLista(struct no *L) {
    no *outra = cria();
    while (L->qnt > 0) {
        outra->dados[outra->qnt] = L->dados[L->qnt - 1];
        L->qnt--;
        outra->qnt++;
    }
    return outra;
}

void clonaValorLista(struct no *L) {
        for (clone.qnt=0; clone.qnt<L->qnt; clone.qnt++){
            clone.dados[clone.qnt] = L->dados[clone.qnt];
            printf("%i\n",clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
        }
}

void push ( struct Pilha *p, float v){

    p->qnt++;
    p->dados[p->qnt] = v;

}


void pushclone ( struct PilhaClone *p, float v){

    p->qnt++;
    p->dados[p->qnt] = v;

}

void imprimePilhaPrincipal (struct Pilha *p){

    int aux = p->qnt;
       printf("teste %i\n",p->qnt);

}

float retornaqnt ( struct Pilha *p ){
    return p->dados [p->qnt];
}

void clonaValorPilha(struct no **Pilha){
    int PilhaClone;
    int valorPilha;
    int x;
    (**Pilha).qnt=0;
    /*for (x; x<Pilha.qnt; x++){
        valorPilha = retornaqnt(&Pilha);
        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );

    }*/
    /*for (PilhaClone.qnt=0; PilhaClone.qnt<Pilha->qnt; PilhaClone.qnt++){
        //valorPilha = retornaqnt(&Pilha);
        //PilhaClone.dados[PilhaClone.qnt] = Pilha->dados[PilhaClone.qnt];
        //printf("%i\n",PilhaClone.dados[PilhaClone.qnt]);
    }*/

   /*
    int x=0;
    for (x=0; x < Pilha->qnt; x++){
        PilhaClone.dados[x] = Pilha.dados[x];
        printf("%i\n",PilhaClone.dados[x]);
    }
    */
}


int desempilhar ( struct Pilha *p ){

    int aux = p->dados [p->qnt];
    p->qnt--;
    return aux;

}




int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int valor,op,valorPilha;
    bool listaClonada = false;
    no *L = cria();
    no *clone = cria();
    struct Pilha minhapilha;
    struct PilhaClone minhapilhaclone;
    criarpilha (&minhapilha);
    criarpilhaclone(&minhapilhaclone);

    while( 1 ){
        printf("\n1- Informar Valores Da Lista Principal \n");
        printf("2- Função clonaValorLista (Clona lista Principal)\n");
        printf("3- Exibe lista clonada\n");
        printf("4- Exibe lista principal \n");
        printf("5- Função inverteLista (Inverte a lista Original)\n");
        printf("6- Inserir Valor No Topo Da Pilha Principal\n");
        printf("7- Imprimir Pilha Principal\n");
        printf("8- Função clonaValorPilha\n");
        printf("10- sair\n");

        printf("\nSelecione A Opção: ");
        scanf("%i", &op);
        fflush(stdin);


        switch (op){

            case 1:
                printf("Informe o valor:");
                scanf("%i", &valor);
                insere(L, valor);
                break;

                case 2:
                    printf("Lista Clonada\n");
                    clonaValorLista(L);
                    listaClonada = true;

                break;

                case 3:
                if (listaClonada == false){
                    printf("\nLista ainda não clonada\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("\nValores Clonados\n");
                    exibeClone(L);
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nValores\n");
                exibe(L);
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\nValores Originais:\n");
                exibe(L);
                L = inverteLista(L);
                printf("\nValores Invertidos:\n");
                exibe(L);
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("\nInsira o valor para adicionar ao qnt da pilha princpal: ");
                scanf("%i",&valorPilha);
                push (&minhapilha, valorPilha);
                break;

            case 7:
                if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
                    printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nPilha Principal\n");
                    int aux=minhapilha.qnt;
                    for (minhapilha.qnt; minhapilha.qnt>0; minhapilha.qnt--){
                        valorPilha = retornaqnt(&minhapilha);
                        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
                    }
                    minhapilha.qnt=aux;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                //clonaValorPilha(&minhapilha);
                if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
                    printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nPilha Clonada\n");
                    int aux=minhapilha.qnt;
                    int x= minhapilha.qnt;
                    for (x; x>0; x--){
                        valorPilha = minhapilha.dados[x];
                        pushclone(&minhapilhaclone,valorPilha);
                        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
                    }
                    minhapilhaclone.qnt=aux;
                }
                break;

            case 10:
                exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Sugiro o uso de alguma ferramenta de comparação para que você consiga ver melhor as mudanças que foram feitas. O código inicialmente não estava compilando.

Caso precise que a clonagem da pilha seja em uma função:

```
void clonaValorPilha(struct Pilha *Pilha){
    int PilhaClone;
    int valorPilha;
    int x;
    struct PilhaClone minhapilhaclone;
    criarpilhaclone(&minhapilhaclone);

    if( ( Pilha->qnt == 0 )){
        printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nPilha Clonada\n");
        int aux=Pilha->qnt;
        int x= Pilha->qnt;
        for (x; x>0; x--){
            valorPilha = Pilha->dados[x];
            pushclone(&minhapilhaclone,valorPilha);
            printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
        }
        minhapilhaclone.qnt=aux;
    }
}
```

Na área de chamada:

```
case 8:
    clonaValorPilha(&minhapilha);                
    break;
```

Comment: Obrigado, assim funcionou porém não está fazendo a clonagem pelo método, e sim pelo main, o meu problema é exatamente esse, no main eu devo apenas passar o método, e o método fazer todo o trabalho

Comment: Transformei o que escrevi em uma função (tá mais ao final da minha resposta).
Mas, me parece que o objetivo não é clonar a pilha inteira e sim um valor apenas. Acho melhor você dar uma olhada nisso. Sendo assim, dai sua função mudará bastante.
Mas, sendo o clone da pilha inteira em uma função separada, já funciona.

Answer (score 0):

só complementando o quê eu disse acima, eu preciso fazer tudo pela função, ( o próprio case 7 também está errado).

no case 8 eu queria somente chamar a função clonaValorPilha dando o valor de uma pilha pra ela (no caso a pilha criada no case 6), então a função deve criar o nó da pilha clone (não devo inserir manualmente no main) e inserir os valores lá

no exemplo a a seguir, quando rodo o case 8, o compilador crasha e não consigo continuar, eu gostaria de fazer funcionar apenas na função que citei acima, sem criar funções novas e sem que a main faça alguma alteração, somente a chamada do método.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct no {
    int qnt;
    int dados[];
} no;

no* cria() {
    int qnt=0;
    int dados=0;
    no *L = (no *) malloc(sizeof(no));
    if (L != NULL) {
        L->qnt = 0;
    }
    return L;
}

struct clone {
            int qnt;
            int dados[];
}clone;

struct Pilha {

    int qnt;
    float *dados;

};

struct PilhaClone {

    int qnt;
    float *dados;

}PilhaClone;

void criarpilha( struct Pilha *p){

    p->qnt = 0;
    p->dados = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

}



void criarpilhaclone( struct PilhaClone *p){

    p->qnt = 0;
    p->dados = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

}

void insere(no *L, int valor) {

    L->dados[L->qnt] = valor;
    L->qnt++;

}

void exibeLista(no *L) {
    for (int i = 0; i < L->qnt; i++)
        printf("%3d\n", L->dados[i]);
}

void exibeListaClone(no *L) {
    for (clone.qnt= 0; clone.qnt < L->qnt; clone.qnt++)
        printf("%i\n", clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
}

no* inverteLista(struct no *L) {
    no *outra = cria();
    while (L->qnt > 0) {
        outra->dados[outra->qnt] = L->dados[L->qnt - 1];
        L->qnt--;
        outra->qnt++;
    }
    return outra;
}

void clonaValorLista(struct no *L) {
        for (clone.qnt=0; clone.qnt<L->qnt; clone.qnt++){
            clone.dados[clone.qnt] = L->dados[clone.qnt];
            printf("%i\n",clone.dados[clone.qnt]);
        }
}

void push ( struct Pilha *p, float v){

    p->qnt++;
    p->dados[p->qnt] = v;

}

void imprimePilhaPrincipal (struct Pilha *p){

    int aux = p->qnt;
       printf("teste %i\n",p->qnt);

}

float retornaqnt ( struct Pilha *p ){
    return p->dados [p->qnt];
}

void clonaValorPilha(struct no **Pilha){
    int PilhaClone;
    int valorPilha;
    int x= (**Pilha).qnt;
                    for (x; x>0; x--){
                        valorPilha = (**Pilha).dados[x];
                        push(&Pilha,valorPilha);
                        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
                    }
}


int desempilhar ( struct Pilha *p ){

    int aux = p->dados [p->qnt];
    p->qnt--;
    return aux;

}




int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int valor,op,valorPilha;
    bool listaClonada = false;
    no *L = cria();
    no *clone = cria();
    struct Pilha minhapilha;
    criarpilha (&minhapilha);


    while( 1 ){
        printf("\n1- Informar Valores Da Lista Principal \n");
        printf("2- Função clonaValorLista (Clona lista Principal)\n");
        printf("3- Exibe lista clonada\n");
        printf("4- Exibe lista principal \n");
        printf("5- Função inverteLista (Inverte a lista Original)\n");
        printf("6- Inserir Valor No Topo Da Pilha Principal\n");
        printf("7- Imprimir Pilha Principal\n");
        printf("8- Função clonaValorPilha\n");
        printf("10- sair\n");

        printf("\nSelecione A Opção: ");
        scanf("%i", &op);
        fflush(stdin);


        switch (op){

            case 1:
                printf("Informe o valor:");
                scanf("%i", &valor);
                insere(L, valor);
                break;

                case 2:
                    printf("Lista Clonada\n");
                    clonaValorLista(L);
                    listaClonada = true;

                break;

                case 3:
                if (listaClonada == false){
                    printf("\nLista ainda não clonada\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("\nValores Clonados\n");
                    exibeListaClone(L);
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nValores\n");
                exibeLista(L);
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\nValores Originais:\n");
                exibeLista(L);
                L = inverteLista(L);
                printf("\nValores Invertidos:\n");
                exibeLista(L);
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("\nInsira o valor para adicionar ao qnt da pilha princpal: ");
                scanf("%i",&valorPilha);
                push (&minhapilha, valorPilha);
                break;

            case 7:
                if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
                    printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nPilha Principal\n");
                    int aux=minhapilha.qnt;
                    for (minhapilha.qnt; minhapilha.qnt>0; minhapilha.qnt--){
                        valorPilha = retornaqnt(&minhapilha);
                        printf ( "%.1i\n", valorPilha );
                    }
                    minhapilha.qnt=aux;
                }
                break;
            case 8:

                if( minhapilha.qnt == 0 ){
                    printf("\nA pilha principal ainda está vazia\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nPilha Clonada\n");
                    clonaValorPilha(&minhapilha);
                }
                break;

                case 9:

                break;

            case 10:
                exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```